# Optimization in Python for simple linear function

Tags: python

> If the price charged for a crayon is p cents, then `x` thousand crayons
>   will be sold in a certain school store, where `p(x)= 122-x/34` .
>   Using Python, calculate how many crayons must be sold to maximize
>   revenue.

I can solve this by hand much easily, the only problem is how can I do it using plain Python? I am using IDLE (Python GUI). I am new to Python and haven't downloaded any external libraries. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What I've done up to this point is

```
import math

def f(x):
    return (122-(x/34.0))
def g(x):
    return x*f(x)
def h(x):
    return (122-(2*x/34.0))
```

Comment: Have you *attempted* to translate your hand-written solution into Python yet? Also, unlike MathStack, StackOverflow does not have LaTeX support.

Comment: I don't understand why people would down vote something like this. This is really rude.
import math
def f(x):
    reurn (122-(x/34.0))
def g(x):
    return x*f(x)
def h(x):
    return (122-(2*x/34.0))
Am i all good upto this?

Comment: People just don't appreciate a question that doesn't reflect any effort on the asker's part.

Comment: How to solve h(x) for x? also, Can i make it any better?

Comment: @iced, Why would you say something like that if I am willing to learn it? This very discouraging

Comment: @iced Python is one of the best languages for mathematical computing and this is a solid question. Mathematica and haskell also aren't even comparable and python is significantly better than haskell here

Comment: @Mathematician Don't pay attention to iced, he's being very negative, there's a good solution here though the question could have been asked more clearly. Will follow up shortly with an answer.

Comment: @iced Flagged comment again for being incredibly unconstructive.

Comment: you are thinking about your badges, not about teaching people. worst thing you can do is to teach him voodoo ritual to solve this particular problem. flag it whatever you want. @Mathematician - you'll be able to solve your problem (as well as many others) after short (they estimate it to 13h) tutorial I mentioned before. ps flagged last Elizion comment as unconstructive.

Comment: @iced Your comment is not constructive because as opposed to providing any input to help the OP either answer or improve his question, you are telling him that he should just go take a tutorial instead. That is hardly a constructive comment, as it could apply to nearly every single question on all of Stack Overflow. "If you don't know how to do something, go read a book/take a tutorial/learn more, etc." Stack Overflow is for providing people with quality answers, not telling them to go take a plethora of tutorials, so long as they have demonstrated that they have a minimal understanding.

Comment: he doesn't even know what is python function and how it's different from math function. what other good solution but taking small python tutorial you see?

Answer (score 2):

Use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/pt/index.html). It's simple, beautiful and powerful.

You can write down your equations with `simpify()`, like that:

```
p = simpify('122 - x/34')
```

And define symbols for symbolic evaluation with `Symbol()` and `symbols()`.
With that you can do things like simply use `solve()` function for any given equation. i.e. `x + 4 = 2x`:

```
res = solve('x + 4 - 2*x')
```

It's pretty much the tool I use for any math work with python.

Comment: Sympy is an excellent library, but lacks a good deal of functionality around more complex mathematical functions like function optimization.

Comment: Thank you, I got much information from this, however, when I try to integrate something, it gives me error invalid limits given

Answer (score 1):

So, you should go and download an external library for this, as it's not functionality that `python` makes easy to implement natively. Also, if you're serious about doing mathematical computation in `python` I would suggest switching operating systems to something like OSX or linux, simply because compiling old FORTRAN libraries (required for much performant mathematical computing) is a huge pain on Windows.

You have to make use of the `scipy` library here, which has an optimize module. Specifically I would suggest using the `optimize.minimize_scalar` function. Docs can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar).

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
>>> def g(x):
...     return -(x*(122 - (x/34)))  # inverse because you're minimizing.
>>> minimize_scalar(g, bounds=(1, 10000), method='bounded')
  status: 0
    nfev: 6
 success: True
     fun: -126514.0
       x: 2074.0
 message: 'Solution found.'
```

Comment: Installing scientific python modules, including `scipy` on any platform (OSX, Linux or Windows) is not hat hard with Anadonda or a number of other scientific python distributions.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, Is there any way without using any external libraries to solve a simple linear equation in one variable, You can see I can manually put all the functions, but I don't see any point in doing everything by hand !

Comment: @rth getting an installation isn't too difficult, but if scientific computing is something you want to dig into, you will at points have to use libraries not yet a part of conda, or recompile with specific flags, which gets more difficult on non *nix machines.

Comment: @Mathematician, no, native python doesn't have a lot of scientific computing capability, so it turns into a math problem on your side. If you really want to learn `python` though, the external libraries are FAR more important than the language itself.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I completely agree that having a decent terminal and *nix environment is very convenient, however python is platform independent and so are a Cython and f2py. And it's not like C/Fortran libraries can't be compiled on Windows. My point is that advising someone looking into simple optimization problems with Python to change the OS is a bit off topic [ linux user here].

Comment: I don't get x=4148, while doing it manuallly. It is exactly twice of what I got.

Comment: @Mathematician ah, that's totally my bad, shouldn't have taken an inverse, but instead the negative.

Comment: @rth if the goal was only to solve this problem and stop I'd agree, but as the specification here was someone trying to dive into numerical computing (at least from my read), I think it's really relevant than OS becomes the limiting factor sooner than you'd think.